# ListView doesn't update when its model data changes

Tags: qt, qml

I have a `QList<QObject*>` that is read from within a `ListView` module into a `model`. At first the QList is an empty object. I want the `indexBackup` to be updated when I assign a new list to the `QList` object.

```
import QtQuick          2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts  1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.0

ListView {
    id: layersListView

    model: settingsList   //QList<QObject*> object
    int indexBackup: 0

    onModelChanged: {
        if(indexBackup && indexBackup < model.length) 
        {
            indexBackup = model.length
        }
        else 
        {
            indexBackup = - 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everybody with similar problem, the answer can be found [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/103482/listview-model-update/3).